# Parsing auto parts site Python + beautifulsoup. I can not collect the links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to go through the list of categories in the nav tag, follow the links in each subcategory so that I can collect information on the products. However, the parser does not find any links to the category page. how to Get links to collect information about products.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ipdusa.com"

headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1"
}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
src = req.text
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html")
results = soup.find('div', {'class',"category-cell large novehicle"}).findAll('a', 'href')

print(results)
```

Output:
`[]`

Comment: The site completes the hrefs for this objects using JavaScript. You probably can't get then using beautifulsoup. You should use Selenium in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by selenium

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

res = driver.get("https://www.ipdusa.com")
# wait for ajax content list 
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "category-cell"))
)
# get innerHtml 
html = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all('a'))
driver.quit()
```